# loopback gives undefined on modelName.afterRemoteError

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

```
Member.afterRemoteError('assignDepartment', function (ctx, next) {
    console.log("in after remote error");
    next();
  });
```

[image]

I tried

> console.log(Member.afterRemoteError)

but got undefined :(

I am using strongloop v3.0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though that has [not yet been released](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/commits/master), and thus its inclusion in documentation was premature.

Expect `ModelCtor.afterRemoteError` to be implemented in the next release. You can get it today if you pull the dependency from github.